# Errors when starting plutus-playground.server

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, plutus-pioneer-program

I have built, run, compiled, simulated, and evaluated on my local nix server/client env. I am running Ubuntu 21.04, Kernal 5.11.0-46lowlatency.

Here is the terminal output:

```
[Info] Running: (Nothing,Webserver {_port = 8080, _maxInterpretationTime = 80s})
Initializing Context
Initializing Context
Warning: GITHUB_CLIENT_ID not set
Warning: GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET not set
Warning: JWT_SIGNATURE not set

Interpreter ready
```

I actually already asked about the GitHub ID in another question, but am looking for guidance on the `JWT_SIGNATURE` setting indicated in t he last warning line before Interpreter ready statement.

Or, am I missing something more obvious than that, like the `(Nothing,Webserver{...})` statement in line 1?

Thank you for any help in advance!!

Comment: I have got the same warning when running the plutus-playground-server locally. You should be able to use the Playground despite there is a warning. I think this is only needed if the playground will be deployed somewhere and you want to offer a Login via Github Open Auth flow.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, Marco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Marco writes, this is fine. The `(Nothing,Webserver { ... })` line is just informative. The warnings are also of informative value only and do not constitute an actual error.